# Is it possible to enable HTTPS/TLS for Tomcat using OpenSSL without requiring Native Libraries and APR?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https, apr

I am trying to get HTTPS/TLS enabled for Tomacat (8.x) preferring the OpenSSL alternative because the cert/key configuration is simpler (compared to the usual JSSE with keystore).

Followed the [offical documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html) and enabled the connector section like this:

```xml
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
          sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
          maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true">

        <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2">
            <Certificate 
               certificateKeyFile="conf/MyKey.key"
               certificateFile="conf/MyCertificate.crt"
               type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

**NOTE** that I am still using `Http11NioProtocol` and not APR `Http11AprProtocol` connector.

However, startup fails with this configuration as this combination of configuration seems to *require* Tomcat native libraries to be built and configured:

```
14-Jun-2019 10:38:46.363 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:621)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:644)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.tomcat.jni.Pool.create(J)J
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Pool.create(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.<clinit>(OpenSSLEngine.java:70)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getImplementedProtocols(OpenSSLUtil.java:61)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:53)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.<init>(OpenSSLUtil.java:41)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation.getSSLUtil(OpenSSLImplementation.java:36)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1082)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:267)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
```

I did build and install [Tomcat native](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) + [APR](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/apr.html) library and configured in Tomcat env class path which fixed the issue, but that is besides the point. Point is, shouldn't APR/native libraries be only required if I am using `Http11AprProtocol` which I am not using? What am I missing? Any pointers/help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: JSSE is built into Java and doesn't use a native library. OpenSSL isn't, and does.

Comment: Post your edit of 6 hours ago, no, because OpenSSL requires a native library, as I stated above two days ago.

Comment: @user207421 apologies for the confusion. I think I mixed up the connectors and SSL implementations a bit, when trying make "JSSE implementation that uses OpenSSL" option mentioned in docs, work. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake I made was that I had explicitly configured `sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"` in the Connector configuration. This is what causes dependency on native libraries and the error on startup.

Not specifying `sslImplementationName` leaves it to default which is `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation` and works fine with OpenSSL style certificate and key configuration. Final config:

```xml
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
          maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true">

        <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2">
            <Certificate 
               certificateKeyFile="conf/MyKey.key"
               certificateFile="conf/MyCertificate.crt"
               type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

So the answer to the main question: yes it is possible to use pure Java/JSSE style configuration with OpenSSL style SSLHostConfig.

(APR/OpenSSL impl with native libraries are relatively more perform ant, however.)

Comment: Yes it does. Could you be more specific about TLS handshakes - are you aware of any issues with this setup in TLS handshake that you are aware of? I do not see any obvious error to this effect as such.

Comment: This is probably still the problem for Tomcat 10 after you think you have updated server.xml for Nio/Nio2. More of the new error message for search engines: `SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init> Protocol handler instantiation failed
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol`